# whonix/Tor connection error problem

Tags: help, whonix

Can someone please help me because I am having this same issue with Whonix.Tor connection error ?

Possible issues:
1. Is the Internet on the host connection working>>YES

2. WHONIX-GATEWAY will need a few moments for bootstrapping the Tor Network>>Says Bootstrapping 0% Done

3.Did you start gateway beforehand>YES

Recommendations:
Try Again: Start menu > Applications > Systen > Whonix Check 
or in Termin: Whonixcheck
or in terminal with debugging: bash -x whonixcheck --verbose

2.Run whonixcheck on gateway as well.

I TRIED ALL RECOMMENDATIONS AND NOTHING WORKED. PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: Can you give us some log? That could be helpful..

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions. If you have information to add, edit or comment on the original question. I deleted your answer to the original question because it was closer to a comment; however, posting again as a separate question also isn't helpful.

Comment: What's your email so I can send you a screenshot